# Joomla: Uploading an Articulate presentation

Tags: joomla

I have a client who has done some presentations using Articulate.  They have sent me the zip file of a presentation, and I'm trying to upload them into their Joomla site so the presentation can be viewed online.

I've followed the instructions in this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MqqPs6n9rM

I'm unsure if I should make the iframe path be to the player, or the presentation itself.  When on my computer's local drive if I click the player, it will load the presentation.  So I assumed my iframe path should be to the player, but now only the player is loading and no presentation.  I'm unsure where the presentation needs to be in reference to the player for it load.  I mimicked the structure of the directory on my computer but that's not working either.

I'm still pretty new to Joomla, and don't work with Articulate at all, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  If anyone else needs to know, make sure you upload the files through your FTP in binary, not ASCII.  If not, the XML data is messed up.  Other than that, the youtube video I posted above is helpful.